# How do I make stop my nav from overflowing onto my div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am learning front end web development and I am stuck with how to make my website responsive. I am currently trying to stop my navigation from overlapping onto the next div container. How do I do this please and if you have any other tips on how to make my website responsive that would be great thanks.

Am I using the media queries correctly? I'm now aware I should be using a mobile first approach, but at first I was just copying a mockup I saw online so I had to do it the other way around.

My code is on codepen, here: https://codepen.io/wmufunde/pen/vYYWOBy

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Best Bakery Company</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jomolhari|Tangerine|Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="logo-top"><a href="#">Best Bakery Company</a></li>
            <li class= "nav"><a href="#">WELCOME</a></li>
            <li class= "nav"><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
            <li class= "nav"><a href="#">RESERVATIONS</a></li>
            <li class= "nav"><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
            <li class= "nav"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li class= "nav"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
            <li class= "nav"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="headings">
        <h1>Pastry with love</h1>
        <h2>We're bringing you fresh ingredients<br> everyday in ways you can't resist.</h2>
        <button class="btn">Menu</button>
    </div>
</header>

<body>

    <div class="row" id="background1">
        <div class="column">
            <h1>Art of cakes</h1>
            <h2>We create delicious memories</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi. Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac.</p>
            <h3>Chef cook</h3>
            <div = id="chef"><img src="img/chef.jpg" align="middle"></div>
            <p id="cursive">Unique creatives for unique reasons</p>

        </div>

        <div class="column" id="relative">
            <div class ="row-pastry" id="padding">
                <img src="http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/pastry1.jpg">
                <img src="http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/pastry2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="row-pastry">
                <img src="http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/pastry3.jpg">
                <img src="http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/pastry4.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id="icon"><p>TASTES SO <br>GOOD!</p></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row" id="background2">

        <div class="column center"id="white">

            <h1>Tasty Pancakes</h1>
            <h2>Season Favourites</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi. Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac.</p>
            <div class="image-circle">
                <img src="http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/blueberry.jpg">
                <img src="http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/pancake.jpg">
                <img src="http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/pancake2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="background3">
        <div class="column breakfast">
            <h1>Breakfast</h1>
            <p>7AM Breakfast? We're Open!</p>

            <h2>Full Breakfast</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <h3>£12.50</h3>

            <h2>Toast and Jam</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <h3>3.50</h3>

            <h2>Muffins</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <h3>£4.99</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="background4">

        <div class="column meal">
            <img src="http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/page4/wheat.jpg">
            <h1>Wheat</h1>
            <img src="http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/page4/eggs.jpg">
            <h1>Eggs</h1>
            <img src="http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/page4/cheese.jpg">
            <h1>Cheese</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="column sandwich">
            <h1>The Jibarito Sandwich</h1>
            <h2>The Best Sandwich you've Ever Tasted!</h2>
            <img src="http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/page4/sandwich.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5b02610863.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

<footer>
    <ul>
        <li><a href ="#">Our Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href ="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href ="#">Culture</a></li>
        <li id="logo-footer"><a href ="#">Best Bakery Company</a></li>
        <li><a href ="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href ="#">Catering</a></li>
        <li><a href ="#">Visit Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

```
    /* ==========================================
                                            Page 1 & Navigation
============================================ */
header {
    background-image: url("http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/header.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: -20px;
    z-index: 1500;
    width: 100%;
    /* display: block; */

}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    height: 50px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}

 nav ul li  {
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 1%;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

#logo-top {
    font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
    font-size: 45px;
    padding-top: 0;
    flex-grow: 5;
}

nav ul li {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

header h1 {
    font-family: 'Jomolhari', serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

header h2 {
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
#headings {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 80vh;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#headings h1,h2, .btn {
    margin: auto;
}

.btn {
    padding: 20px 80px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-color: black;
    color:white;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* ==========================================
                                            Page2
============================================ */
#background1 {
    background-color: beige;
}

.column{
    width:50vw;

}

.column h1, h2 {
        font-family: 'Jomolhari', serif;
}

.column h1, h2, h3, p, #chef img {
    text-align: center;
}
.column h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #330000;

}

.column h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: saddlebrown;

}

.column p {
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;

}

#cursive{
    font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
    font-size:50px;
}
#chef img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 20vh;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row-pastry img {
    height: 25vh;
    width: 150%;

}

.row-pastry {
    width: 25%;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 5vw;
}

#padding {
    padding-top: 15vh;
}

#icon{
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
  top: 27%;
  right: 26.5%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%);


}

#icon p{
    padding-top: 20%;
    padding-left: 35%;
}

#relative {
    position: relative;
}

/* ==========================================
                                        Page 3
============================================ */
#background2 {
     background-image: url(http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/background2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}

.center {
    margin: auto;
}

#white {
background: white;
    height:60%;
    width:50vw;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2%;

}

.image-circle { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    min-height: 50vh;
}
.image-circle img {
    height: 10vh;
    width: 5vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* ==========================================
        Page 4 - Breakfast Menu
============================================ */

#background3 {
     background-image: url(http://wadzanai.co.uk/100daysofcode/Day7/img/background3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    min-width: 50vw;
}

.breakfast {
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    margin:auto;
    width: 25vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* ==========================================
        Page 5 - Sandwich
============================================ */

#background4 {
    background: beige;
    padding: 2%;
}
.meal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-width: 50vw;

}
.meal img {
    width: 10vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

.meal h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
}

.sandwich img {
    width: 33vw;

}

/* ==========================================
                                            Footer
============================================ */

footer {
 background-color: saddlebrown;
}
footer ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color:black;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

footer ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

}

#logo-footer {
    font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
    font-size: 45px;
    flex-grow: 2;
}

/* ==========================================
                                            Transitions and Transforms
============================================ */

li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}

 .btn {
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-property: scale;
}

.fab {
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-property: scale;
}

.fab:hover, .btn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

/* Page 2 */

.image-circle img {
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.image-circle img:hover {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}

/* ==========================================
                                            Page 1 & Navigation Media Queries
============================================ */

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {

    nav ul {
    display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        height: 250px;
        text-align: center;
        }

    footer ul {
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap
        }

    .breakfast {
        width: 50vw;
        }

    .center h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
        }

    .center h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
        }

    .center p {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 625px) {
    .sandwich h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .sandwich h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .row-pastry {
        flex-direction: column;

    }

    .row-pastry img {

    height: auto;
    }

    #icon {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: why is your ```<footer>``` tag out of the ```<body>```?

Comment: And ```<header>``` is also outside the ```<body>```. Is there a reason for you to do so?